# Formula to select range by condition in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I'm looking for a formula that summarizes a range of a column, filtered by a condition of another column in same row, e.g. the `SUM` of column `B` where value in column `A` is greater than `x`.

For example I want to have the sum of column `F`, where the date in column `E` of that row is within a week from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,"<"&TODAY()+7,F:F)`
```

Comment: The problem is that the value I have to evaluate is not a scalar number. Here's what I need: `=SUMIF(E:E, DATEVALUE(E:E) < (DATEVALUE(TODAY()) + 7), F:F)`. And to explain, I want to show a summary of all `E`, that their date (`D` col), is within next week.

Comment: I see, does this work instead: =SUMIF(E:E,"<"&TODAY()+7,F:F)

Comment: Thanks you very much!